# Textbox - bound property value does not update immediately

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a textbox which is bound to a property `ItemID` like so.

```
private string _itemID;
public string ItemID {
    get { return _itemID; }
    set { 
        _itemID = value;
    }
}
```

The XAML of the text box is as follows:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ItemID, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="txtItemID" />
```

The problem is, the value of `ItemID` does not update immediately as I type,
causing the `Add` button to be disabled (command), until I lose focus of the text box by pressing the tab key.

Comment: Hi Edwin, I think you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged event handler. This may be the reason why it isn't updating. The INotifyPropertyChanged is set within your Property and Notifies the UI that it has been changed. also, within your xaml, add; `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

Comment: I agree with you @gregory.bmclub

Comment: Ah yes it does! My apologies. Its marked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, by default, the property would be updated only on lost focus. This is to improve performance by avoiding the update of bound property on every keystroke. You should use **UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged**.

Try this:

```
<TextBox 
    Text="{Binding Path=ItemID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    Name="txtItemID" />
```

You should also implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for your ViewModel. Else, if the property is changed in the ViewModel, the UI would not get to know about it. Hence it would not be updated. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) might help in implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fire the OnPropertyChanged event in the setter, otherwise the framework has no way of knowing that you edited the property.

Here are some examples:

[Implementing NotifyPropertyChanged without magic strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728465/implementing-notifypropertychanged-without-magic-strings)

[Notify PropertyChanged after object update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513166/notify-propertychanged-after-object-update)

Comment: He is not facing a problem with property update. The property is getting updated properly after entering text in textbox. He is facing the issue that the property is not updating on each keystroke. What you are answering is regarding property binding with the control. This is already there.