# Notifying all properties of the viewmodel has changed with null or string empty

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, inotifypropertychanged

I'm coming from developing WPF solutions where to update all properties of the viewmodel was as simple as:

```
OnPropertyChanged(String.Empty);
```

In the Universal Windows Platform scenario, I just have the same method to update/refresh the properties. This works fine in most of cases but sometimes it raise an error something like this:

> COMException Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.     at System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)     at GeekyTool.Base.BindableBase.OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)     at Pooo.set_Root(UserRoot value)     at Booo.d__26.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     at GeekyTool.Base.PageBase.d__1.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.b__6_0(Object state)     at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()

The `OnPropertyChanged` method with an `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface implementation look like this:

```
public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public virtual bool Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can explore the mvvm library, but nothing different on the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.

[GeekyTool Library on Github](https://github.com/dachibox/GeekyTool/blob/dev/src/GeekyTool.Core/Base/BindableBase.cs)

Comment: I surprised if this ever worked on UWP. There is nothing special in the code to handle a property name of `String.Empty`. Do you have a full repro available? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MattLacey, raising the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event with `string.empty` is an "old" trick that AFAIK, works fine in UWP to force all (classical or compiled) bindings to refresh!

Comment: if you are using x:bind you can call 'this.Bindings.Update()' from the code behind of the page to force all bindings on that page to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank's for all the answers, I was trying to fix an error that it isn't was there.

In the OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty) method raise the error because it comes with an sync context issue from the page before.

It happens when you are navigating between two page very fast and has some async calls in the OnNavigatedTo method where they aren't finished yet. The async method are awaited, but in this page was not handled that the user wait until this is finished.

Just to know that no need to apply @PedroLamas fix. Ensuring on the page before that all async calls are finished it's done.

Answer (score 2):

I see on the stack trace that there's some async code, so I'd suggest only invoking `OnPropertyChanged(String.Empty)` with the `Dispatcher`, like so:

```csharp
Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty);
});
```

Comment: The question is that the OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty); is done in a setter, so what I can do is an async operation without awaiting it. Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: Correct, you don't need to await that `Dispatcher` call, it doesn't matter for what you need here!

Answer (score 1):

CallerMemeberName pulls calling member name if you pass in nothing (or null) that isn’t the same string.empty

I’d fix that first.

```
public bool IsValid
{
    get { return isValid; }
    set
    {
        if (isValid == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        isValid = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

This should work. Often where I can’t use ReactiveObject or ObservableObject I tend to use this.

Comment: Yes, but as @PedroLamas says, raising the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event with `string.Empty` is an "old" trick to force all binding to update/refresh. That is what I'm doing, updating all at once.